# Check if value is positive or negative

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to write a query which checks if 2 amounts have the same sign (+ or -).
Do you have a good solutions that can be used?

Something like: If SAMESIGN(value1, value2) then do something

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
CASE WHEN (value1 * value2) < 0 THEN 'DiffSign' ELSE 'SameSignOrOneIsZero' END
```

Answer (score 11):

Try to use sign function as below

```
case 
when sign(value1)=sign(value2) then 'the same sign'
else 'different sign'
end
```

- [**SIGN function**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188420.aspx)

Comment: Don't know what this is not accepted answer, it should be faster then multiplying 2 numbers